# Get correct text display from excel with IExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

**tl;dr**: How to get display text in excel file instead of value after convert to string.

I have an Excel file from upload control, convert it to `DataSet` by `IExcelDataReader` and select a table in it. In some cases, I got incorrect value of string with `datatable.Rows[x][y].ToString()`.
For example, cell with text like `44.123` will return `44,123` after `.ToString()` method but I want exactly string `44.123`. I can fix it by add ` before cell value in excel to convert it from double to string format. But I don't know when cell have that format and want do it programmatically in c# code.
 Please give me some advice. Thank you!

Comment: are you in europe region?

Comment: My OS setting is in US.

Comment: .ToString() method doesn't do any formatting change unless you specify it. had you set your datatable locale (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.locale(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: when I check `datatable.Rows[x][y]` value, it is `44.123` but after `.ToString()` method, value I get is `44,123`

I don't set locale for my table. If it help, what `CultureInfo` I should use?

Comment: use en-Us and try to set it the locale.

Comment: Thank you but this solution do not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,
try this:

```
Convert.ToString("...", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Greetings

Comment: Thank for your reply. That column store random text value, and the issue happend only when text value in double form. So I don't want replace all point with dot in result string.

Comment: Hello, so you can try this:
'.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));'

Comment: That return argument error: `No overload for method ToString take 1 arguments`

Comment: Strange, what about this?
`Convert.ToString("...", new CultureInfo("en-US"));`

Comment: that worked! Thanks alot. Please update your answer so I cant accept it